# Return another page from Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In MVC we used to have `return View("foo",modeldata)`, so I could return any arbitrary view with its associated model. How do I do something like that in 
Razor Pages? I'm looking for something like

```
var p=new ListingPageModel();
// populate p model
return p.Page();
```

I have tried this, to no avail:

```
HttpContext.Request.Path = "/listado";
HttpContext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString("");
ListadoModel l = new ListadoModel();
l.Listing= myListing.ToList();
l.PageContext = new PageContext(this.PageContext);
return l.Page();
```

Comment: Did you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio ? Reading it quickly, I stepped on `RedirectToPage` somewhere, so I think it's what you need. Also consider using [tag:razor-pages] tag instead of [tag:razor].

Comment: That's not quite what I want. RedirectToPage will issue a response to the browser so it asks a different route to the server. I want to do all the processing in the server

Comment: I just found about ViewComponents, which are fine for my use case. I just expected that there were some kind of Razor Page-based ViewComponents. As an aside, I haven't been able to RenderPartialAsync a Page passing a Model, which would have been fine too.